# Maximum interpolation error in lagrange interpolation.

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, chebyshev-polynomials

I have the following question:[image]

And the following Lagrange interpolation error bound:[image]
The way I have started to solve the problem is as follow. For me as a worst case is when all infinitely close to one side (say 1) and we want to calculate the opposite side (say -1) thus our Product will become 2^n. I became stuck here and don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're estimating $\sin$ here; those derivatives in the numerator are derivatives of $\sin$. That means they alternate between sines and cosines - and there's a nice uniform bound we can put on them. No matter what $\xi$ is, $|f^{(n+1)}(\xi)|\le 1$.

And with that, you have a bound $\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ for $|f(x)-p(x)|$ in $[-1,1]$ that depends only on $n$.